# Setting up ng-options with custom index's

Tags: html, angularjs, select, ng-options

I am new to AngularJS and trying to set up a few `ng-options` which have unique indexes. I have a few tables where I want to set the indexes to the table's Primary Key.

i.e. If I had PK's 1, 3, 4, 5. I would want those indexes only in my `select`.

I first call the information as such, with the "names" being what the `label` should be, and the "ID"'s being the `index`.

```
var query = from champs in db.championLists
            select new
            { 
              cID = champs.ID, 
              cName = champs.Name
            };
```

I call and store this information as **Champions**

```
championService.getResources().success(function (champs) {
    $scope.Champions = champs;
});
```

Now I get confused on the part of actually settting up the information within the HTML. Here is my attempt thus far. (and I already tested to make sure the data is actually reaching the View, I just can't figure out how to set my `select`)

```
<select ng-options="select as cName for cID in Champions" ng-init="index = 0" ng-model="cID[index]">{{Champions.cName}}</select>
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#usage : `champ.cID as champ.cName for champ in Champions` ("select" is not a keyword, you  are supposed to replace it with the property you need set as value of select by AngularJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the "select as" on the ng-options.

```
<select ng-options="champ.cID as champ.cName for champ in Champions" ng-init="index = 0" ng-model="cID[index]">{{champ.cName}}</select>
```

Comment: sooo this works if I have the same number of custom items as ID indexs. The problem is that within one table list I have 20 digit gap (19-39 were removed), so once I hit cID 19 it jumps up to CID 39s value, but the index of the select itself moves up to index 19. How can I fix this?